# Resorting an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

How does one resort an NSMutableArray using an index?

I would like to take an index e.g. 9 and everything up to 9, 0 - 8, needs to be put at the end of the array so the array would look something like this.

9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

in terms of the positioning.

How is this done in objective C?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, that would be "rearranging", not "resorting".  Use subarrayWithRange to extract the separate sections, then addObjectsFromArray to recombine them into a new array.

Comment: Though you could use, eg, sortedArrayUsingFunction to sort the array into the sequence you want, if the sequence can be defined in terms of the array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to **move** objets at **index** 0-8 to the end of the array, that's quite easy:

```
NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0,9); // the range of items to push to the end
// extract the first 9 items in the array to keep them around
NSArray* first9 = [yourArray subarrayWithRange:r];
// remove them from the original NSMutableArray
[yourArray removeObjectsInRange:r];
// add them back to the end
[yourArray addObjectsFromArray:first9];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray implements all the sort functions that [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12) does.